# Dozer unable to map Collection<Interface> member

Tags: java, dozer

I have an object which contains a Collection:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private Collection<Base> bases = new LinkedList<Base>();
    public Collection<Base> getBases() {return bases;}
    public void setBases(final Collection<Base> bases) {this.bases = bases;}
}
```

The implementations of the interface are quite simple:

```
public class BaseOne implements Base {
}

public class BaseTwo implements Base {
}
```

When I run a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testCopyOther() {
    final Wrapper wrapper =  new Wrapper();
    wrapper.getBases().add(new BaseOne());

    final Wrapper copy = dozer.map(wrapper, Wrapper.class);
}
```

I get this exception:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.usamp.biddingtool.model.service.impl.Base.<init>()
    at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:82)
    at org.dozer.factory.ConstructionStrategies$ByConstructor.newInstance(ConstructionStrategies.java:261)
    at org.dozer.factory.ConstructionStrategies$ByConstructor.create(ConstructionStrategies.java:245)
    at org.dozer.factory.DestBeanCreator.create(DestBeanCreator.java:65)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapCustomObject(MappingProcessor.java:489)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:446)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.addOrUpdateToList(MappingProcessor.java:776)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.addOrUpdateToList(MappingProcessor.java:850)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapListToList(MappingProcessor.java:686)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapCollection(MappingProcessor.java:541)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapOrRecurseObject(MappingProcessor.java:434)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapFromFieldMap(MappingProcessor.java:342)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.mapField(MappingProcessor.java:288)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:248)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:197)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:187)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:124)
    at org.dozer.MappingProcessor.map(MappingProcessor.java:119)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)
    at com.usamp.biddingtool.model.service.impl.DozerTest.testCopyOther(DozerTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

So, it seems that Dozer is trying to create an instance of the actual type being used in the collection while the type is just an interface.  Since interfaces cannot be instantiated an error is produced.

I have seen others ask this question, but not really get any specific answer.  Are there any solutions for this issue?

Thanks.
-AP_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a hint to Dozer about implementation of Base. Otherwise it will try to instantiate interface and that is not possible.

  `<mapping>
    <class-a>Wrapper</class-a>
    <class-b>Wrapper</class-b>
    <field>
      <a>bases</a>
      <b>bases</b>
      <a-hint>BaseOne,BaseTwo</a-hint>
      <b-hint>BaseOne,BaseTwo</b-hint>
    </field>
  </mapping>`

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/baseattributes.html

**alternative (update):**

  `<mapping>
    <class-a>BaseOne</class-a>
    <class-b>BaseOne</class-b>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <class-a>BaseTwo</class-a>
    <class-b>BaseTwo</class-b>
  </mapping>`

Comment: There are quite a few of these derivations.  It is not feasible to provide hints for each of the specifics.

Comment: If there are few implementations of Base and a lot of uses you may configure hints in a more global way (see update).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  At the end, I used Spring's ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider to scan for concrete classes in my bean packages and programmatically register them with Dozer.  It would have been nice to find a method of providing a custom object factory to dozer so that I could make this a little more dynamic, however, scanning works during the Application Context creation so it finds all the mappings at the beginning.  I used your "alternative" suggestion to style my programmatic mapping after.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to create a [custom DozerConverter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html). In the converter methods you can check the concrete instance type at runtime.

Comment: I like the cusom converter idea but I don't want to take over entire convwrsion process, just the instanciating of a new 'shell'.  Also, for this mapper I want to make it s default behaviour when everything else fails.  Also, this is not for a single interface as there  are quite a few of these interfaces floating about.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry. The scenario in which I used Dozer also had a couple of special cases and it boiled down to creating some converter classes for these types.